# Flask API works for GET but not for POST methods (heroku)

Tags: python, api, flask, heroku

I run a very spartan app for machine learning inference that's structured as such:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
from joblib import load

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    df = pd.DataFrame(request.json)
    df = df.reindex(columns=feature_columns, fill_value=0)
    prediction = list(ada.predict(df))
    return jsonify({"prediction": int(prediction[0])})

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return "get successful"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ada = load("./model/adaboost_model")
    feature_columns = load("./model/feature_columns")
    app.run()
```

The **requirements.txt**:

```
Flask
gunicorn
pandas
joblib
```

**Procfile**:

`web: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app`

and a Model/ folder which contains the two pickled Adaboost models.

I deployed this on Heroku, the GET on /test endpoint works fine, the app works fine, returns 404 for random requests, and recognizes that /predict only has a POST method. However when I run POST I get an Internal Server error, I'm sure it's not the actual code of the POST method that's causing problems, because a simple POST method I wrote for testing also fails and it doesn't do anything code related.

Locally this runs perfectly fine, tested with Postman, the inference is correct and all. What could be going wrong with the POST requests when deployed on Heroku?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) to see what's causing the server error?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you could see the logs, it says feature_columns is not defined? Why would that not be defined in Heroku but be fine locally? Edit: DONE! I fixed it by putting the loads into the predict() method... Why does this happen? I think it has to do with gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to be with gunicorn and the code that runs  before `app.run()`, transferring the loading of the model and feature columns into the actual POST `predict()` method works perfectly now.

However this isn't optimal, because every time a POST request is made you need to load the model again, but it works and isn't so bad because I will only use this POST method once every hour or so.